# Ho we can the document_signing_url that we are passing in the mail. by using the DocuSign_eSign rails gem API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docusignapi, docusign-sdk

Ho we can the document_signing_url that we are passing in the mail. by using the DocuSign_eSign rails gem.

```
envelope_api = DocuSign_eSign::EnvelopesApi.new(api_client)
response = envelope_api.create_envelope(account_id, envelope_definition)
{:documents=>[{:documentBase64=>"", :documentId=>"123", :fileExtention=>"pdf", :name=>"document"}],:emailSubject=>"testmail", :recipients=>{:signers=>[{:email=>"abc@gmail.com.com", :name=>"abc", :recipientId=>"1234"}]}, :status=>"sent"}
recipient_view_request = DocuSign_eSign::RecipientViewRequest.new
recipient_view_request.return_url = "http://example.com"
recipient_view_request.authentication_method = 'None'
recipient_view_request.email = "abc@gmail.com"
recipient_view_request.user_name = "abc"
signing_url = envelopes_api.create_recipient_view(account_id, response.envelope_id, recipient_view_request)
signing_url.url
```

I have tried above line of code, but i am getting only the view url, I need signing_url that we are passing in the envelope mail to user.
Actually we have a fuctionality in our project that user will click on sign_document button, then will sign his uploaded document.
For this i need that signing url which we are sending in the mail on creating the envelope.

Answer (score 0):

The issue with your code is that the email address is different for the signer.

The email and name of the signer must be identical when you make the call to `create_recipient_view()` as it was when you made the call to `create_envelope()`

That will allow you to get a URL for [embedded signing](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/how-to/request-signature-in-cors-app-embedded/) that make it possible for your integration to have users sign an envelope inside your app.

Ruby code is at https://github.com/docusign/code-examples-ruby/blob/main/app/services/e_sign/eg001_embedded_signing_service.rb
and the relevant code is:

```
def make_recipient_view_request(signer_client_id, ds_return_url, ds_ping_url)
    view_request = DocuSign_eSign::RecipientViewRequest.new
    view_request.return_url = ds_return_url + '?state=123'

    view_request.authentication_method = 'none'

    view_request.email = signer_email
    view_request.user_name = signer_name
    view_request.client_user_id = signer_client_id

    view_request.ping_frequency = '600' # seconds
    view_request.ping_url = ds_ping_url # Optional setting

    view_request
  end
```

Comment: I have tried with the same email_id, not not working, can you please share the that 
 peace of code with here.

Comment: what error do you get?

Comment: updated my answer with code and link to GitHub